# How to set default accent colors and styles in Android custom builds?

Tags: android, android-source

I am building a customized Android, and Android 11 has a style feature that allows me to change accent colors, fonts, icons, etc. What file do I need to edit to set the default icons and accent colors?

Android 11 style settings screen:

[image]

Comment: you can check it here I think https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/color-theming